# Create checkboxes from value and sliders on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create checkboxes from a slider, the value will be the number of the created checkboxes. Each checkbox will create a slider onclick and the sliders must also have the value printed to know it.

I'm not sure how to create the first slider but I found a way using jquery:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    value: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#result" ).html( ui.value );
    }
});
```

And the div for the slider is:

```
<div id="slider" class="slider"></div><br>
Quantity: <span id="result">1</span>
```

The checkboxes should be in a group:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="custom" />
       <label for="checkbox-1">1</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I'll be able to create the elements using the jquery method append, but I'm not really sure how to do the rest of the events. I need some help.

Thanks!

Comment: `from a slider` You should provide in question reference to this plugin slider and surely check relevant DOC.

Comment: Sounds like a circular reference ... checkboxes create sliders and sliders create checkboxes. Really not clear what you are wanting to do

Comment: There is 1 slider, this creates checkboxes and these creates sliders. Sounds that bad? :P Edit: Well... in fact the first slider does not create nothing, it's the value number who creates the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.

This create the checkboxes:

```
$("#slider").slider({
  min: 1,
  max: 30,
  value: 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    // Min num
    var start = 1;

    $( "#result" ).html( ui.value );
    // Clear the div
    $('#showChck').html('');

    // Array to create the checkboxes
    $(new Array(ui.value)).each(function () {

      // Add the new checkbox
      $('#showChck').prepend(
        $('<input/>', {type: "checkbox", name: "checkbox-" + start, id: "checkbox-" + start, class: "custom", title: "Cambiar los canales que tendrá la linea: " + start}),
        $('<label/>', {for: 'checkbox-' + start }).text(start)
      );

      // Increase
      start++;
    });
  }
});
```

And this create the sliders:

```
$('body').on('click', '#showChck input', function() {
    var x = this.id;
    var $id = x.replace(/\D/g, '');

    if ($("#slider-" + $id).length) {
        $("#slider-" + $id).fadeToggle();
        $("#result-" + $id).fadeToggle();
    }
    else {
        $("#showSldr").append(
            $('<div/>', {id: "slider-" + $id, class: "slider", title: "Estos son los canales que tendrá la linea: " + $id}),
            $('<span/>', {id: 'result-' + $id}).text($id)
        );
        $("#slider-" + $id).slider({
            min: 4,
            max: 100,
            value: 4,
            step: 2,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#result-" + $id ).html( ui.value );
            }
        });
    }
});
```